# ms teams print logged in username

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have some  assignment like:

- An alerts is sent to a channel in ms teams and awaiting approval
- when user clicks captions in order to approve.

Question: how to print the name of username who approved on the chat channel using adaptive card?

Comment: Can any one please comment as if anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of user who approved on the chat channel from turncontext's activity.

Comment: Thank you , will take a look.